# Hide component that renders a Tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component that renders `Tabs` component from `Material UI 5.0.0-beta.5`

There is a case when I set this components display to none.

But, then I get this error -

`Material-UI: The value provided to the Tabs component is invalid. The Tab with this value (`0`) is not part of the document layout. Make sure the tab item is present in the document or that it's not display none.`

I understand the error, and  I am setting its display to none because but I wanna show and hide the component without re-rendering (because I want the user selections to persist).

Is there a way to fix this error or maybe a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **You could try to use `visibility: hidden` instead**

And if you want not to take up the space to the hidden component, set its width and height to 0 and then change them later to show the UI.

```
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
height: 0;
```

**And when you want to show it back:**

```
visibility: visible;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: This answer is awesome: concise and really effective. Nice one!